# cucumber jvm close browser after running all features

Tags: java, spring, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I'm testing a Spring Boot app using Cucumber-JVM and Selenium. I'm defining a web driver bean and passing a destroy method to quit (shutdown the webdriver and all instances of Chrome) but it is leaving the browser open.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.rodmccutcheon.pensionator.bdd")
public class CucumberConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "quit")
    public WebDriver webDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
        return new ChromeDriver();
    }

}
```

I've basically copied an example from the Cucumber for Java book. The difference is they use xml configuration and I've opted for Java configuration.

```
<bean class="org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver" destroy-method="quit">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

How do I get the browser to close at the end of all tests?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the destroy method to quit to a separate function other than `public WebDriver webDriver()` as here you are creating the driver instance?

Comment: I think it should work. I've basically copied an example from the Cucumber for Java book. The difference is they use xml configuration and I've opted for Java configuration. See edit above for code snippet.

Comment: IMO, it shouldn't as `public WebDriver webDriver()` is returning a `WebDriver` instance where as to destroy or quit the browser instance you need to invoke `quit()` explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought the default bean scope was singleton, but the browser is correctly shut down if I add @Scope("singleton"). eg:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "quit")
@Scope("singleton")
public WebDriver webDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
    return new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you've been downvoted, this is exactly what fixed it for me too!

Answer (score 0):

do you have the following code in your java class ?

```
public void quit()  {
      driver.quit();
    }
```

In your bean definition, you are initialising the driver. By convention , you should use init-method attribute for setup and destroy-method attribute for teardown.

the bean should look like this.

```
WebDriver driver;

public void initDriver(){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

public void quit(){
driver.quit();
}

@Bean(init-method="initDriver" , destroy-Method = "quit")
    public void testUrl() {
    driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
    driver.getTitle();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably just that you picked the wrong attribute of the annotation (or simply a typo). Instead of using **destroyMethod** you should use **destroyMethodName**. Refer to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.rodmccutcheon.pensionator.bdd")
public class CucumberConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethodName = "quit")
    public WebDriver webDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
        return new ChromeDriver();
    }

}
```