# how to quit my selenium webdriver when using it as a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, selenium, junit, cucumber

I'm currently working on a TA project including web automation.
I wanted to use spring dependency injection to not have to pass my webDriver everywhere I want to use it (and for other reasons). For this I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnjvvf2if6Y&list=PL6tu16kXT9PrDr6kMGQ-CgnvCsFxrq1eS&index=15

In short: I have a own "MyWebDriver" class, which has a @Bean annotated methods with initializes the actual WebDriver for me.

```
public class MyWebDriver(){
    @Bean
    public WebDriver initWebdriver(){
        init...
        return new ChromeDriver();
    }

}
```

for now this works as i have expected, but i have trouble quitting my browser after my testrun is finished. As the WebDriver has a "close" Method, I would expect Spring to call it before destroying my bean, but even if I write e.g.
`"@Bean(destroyMethod = "quit")"`
nothing happens.My browser stays open. I know that there are @PreDestroy methods possible with spring, but I don't know how to call it on a bean created with a method.

How do I achieve the goal to close my Browser after the whole testrun is finished?

I can't use cucumbers @After annotations, because that is executed after each testrun and I still may need the browser.

I can't use other ways of cucumber or JUnit to do this, because when this is executed my spring-beans don't exist anymore, e.g. all the stuff [here](https://metamorphant.de/blog/posts/2020-03-10-beforeall-afterall-cucumber-jvm-junit/) doesn't work.

I use a JUnit Runner with `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` annotation and Options etc. to run my tests

How do I close my browser after each testrun?

And another optional thing, which may just not work when I want to use Spring: How do only start the browser, wenn needed and not immediately after start of the testrun?

Comment: What about `@AfterClass` annotation?

Comment: For what you might need Browser after `@After`?

Comment: for the next scenario
the spring context gets initialized once and then i want to execute x scenarios and close the browser after the last

@pburgr doesn't work, because my spring beans don't exist anymore

Comment: you'll need to call driver.quit() method.... that will send a command to the webdriver.  I don't think Spring is going to do that for you.  WebDriver is an interface or type... but it gets further defined when you create a new one.  (In your case it'll be a Chromedriver class that implements webdriver..)  but the actual webdriver is an executable file... in your case it's chromedriver.  Spring knows nothing about this file... it's basically a service that's started.

Comment: Does anyone have even read the question above or is it really written so bad by me?
Yes i know what to do, to quit the webdriver, just WHERE do i do it, to quit the webdriver after my whole Testrun (e.g. after all my 5 scenarios i run)
No i CAN'T use JUnits Annotations because my Spring bean is already destroyed when they are called, and also Cucumbers "AfterTestRun" Handler doesn't work because of the same reason.

Comment: Maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278043/cucumber-jvm-close-browser-after-running-all-features

Comment: Yep, that's exactly my issue, didn't find this topic, thank you!

Comment: as @pcalkins pointed out, its a duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278043/cucumber-jvm-close-browser-after-running-all-features

Comment: did you create the quit method and then use the destroy-Method = "quit" option in the bean annotation?  (I would really question why you are using spring or cucumber here... unless you have to, I'd avoid using those frameworks...)

Comment: the selenium webdriver has close() and quit() methods. Regarding to spring doc before the @Beans are destroyed spring should try and search methods with the name "close" and call them, but that didn't work.
so i used destroyMethod = "quit" in bean annotation, yes and together with scope("singleton") this works.
Cucumber is "have to".
Spring was my own idea, but i'm indeed already in doubt, if this was a good idea, it has some nice features, but the setup is tricky too

Comment: The webdriver the close() method will only close the current browser window/tab.  (depending on the driver it may also close the driver if there are no longer any browser windows open...)  The driver.quit() method will first close the browser and then exit the webdriver, so it's much safer... (you won't have an orphaned driver exe left running after your tests...)

Comment: yes i know the differences between the two methods.
It's just that i would have expected spring to automatically call the close() method on my WebDriver bean